# Mark object as requiring some 'self-type' annotations

Tags: scala, slick

I'm using Slick framework in my Lift scala app. This framework requires presence of ExtendedProfile.simple._ in all of DDL objects. For the moment I have it defined as

```
trait DatabaseProvider {
  val profile : ExtendedProfile
}


trait PersistUser {
  this : DatabaseProvider => 

  import profile.simple._

  object Users extends Table[(String, String, Boolean)]("user") {
      //  various definitions are here
  }
}
```

what I want is to move object **Users** outside of the trait, so I can use it separately in different traits like that for table joining. But I don't know how can I make Users object depend on presence of DatabaseProvider in scope, and import all required stuff.

Please advice.

Comment: I don't 100% what you would like to do. Could you give an example of what you want to do and does not work? It seems to me at the moment that you could pass the specific `DatabaseProvider` you need to the `Users` object.

Comment: basically I want to separate DDL objects like User, and move them out of trait, so I can use them alone.

Comment: What prevents you from putting `Users` outside of the trait?

Comment: I need to have that ExtendedProfile.simple._ in scope.

Comment: What does use it? The `Table`?

Comment: Table is requiring some implicit parameters, like database-specific driver implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could something like this, although I'm not sure it's 100% what you are trying to do.  The idea here is that you can first define a generic schema with all of your table definitions that would not differ between different db providers.  Then, you could extend that per db provider you wanted to support, setting up the actual `object` table definitions that slick needs.  This would give you flexibility to specify the `ExtendedProfile` more dynamically which I believe is what you are aiming for.  I know this compiles, but I did not try and run it.  I guess I'll leave that up to you.

```
import scala.slick.driver.ExtendedProfile
import scala.slick.session.Session

abstract class Schema(val profile:ExtendedProfile){
  import profile.simple._

  abstract class UsersModel extends Table[(String, String, Boolean)]("user") {
    def name = column[String]("name", O.PrimaryKey)
    def email = column[String]("email")
    def valid = column[Boolean]("valid")
    def * = name ~ email ~ valid
  }

  val Users:UsersModel
}

object MySqlSchema extends Schema(scala.slick.driver.MySQLDriver){
  object MySqlUsers extends UsersModel

  val Users:UsersModel = MySqlUsers
}

class UserDAO(schema:Schema)(implicit sess:Session){
  import schema.profile.Implicit._

  def findAllUsers = {
    val q = for(u <- schema.Users) yield u
    q.list
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of an object, make it `class Users(dbProvider: DatabaseProvider) extends Table`... or give it the same self-type as PersistUser

Comment: it should be object, not a class

Comment: why should it be an object?  you essentially want to parameterize this thing on a DatabaseProvider *somehow*, but an object cannot be parameterized.  You got around this before by putting it in an instance of a trait which is parameterized on this DatabaseProvider, If you want it to live outside of this, its going to need to be parameterized on the DatabaseProvider some other way.

Comment: @stew I think the ORM requires it to be an object. Probably to have a named singleton type.